# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_port_handle'

Tags: python, pyserial, attributeerror

I want to communicate in Python using pySerial with a serial interface, but my problem is that I get this Error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_port_handle'" when I start my program.
Here is my code:

```
import serial
serial.Serial.__init__("COM11", 115200, serial.EIGHTBITS, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
```

I hope someone can help me, because everybody on the Internet has the same code to init the serial port.

Comment: " everybody on the Internet has the same code to init the serial port" => well, obviously not.

Comment: https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports - maybe reading the doc would be a good start ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't even bothered reading the doc.

Answer (score 1):

Never call `__init__()` directly. This is the constructor method, and is called implicitly when you construct an object.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__

Try:

```
serial.Serial("COM11", 115200, serial.EIGHTBITS, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE)
```

And if that does not work, check the signature of this `Serial` class. It's possible that the first parameter you give is not supposed to be a `str`. But that should fix it.

The doc to this `__init__()` is there: https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.__init__

And it feels that your parameters are all tangled up. Try naming them in the constructor.

Comment: The reason for the error is that the `__init__()` method always takes `self` as the first parameter. The OP called with a string as the first parameter, hence the error and the effect of tangled up params.

Comment: Actually, yes, **do** call `__init__()` directly, most often from the init method of a derived class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the **init**() method. You simple write serial.Serial(...). 
[see here](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html)